# Calling a Controller Action from a TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using a simple CMS to build a website and have a requirement to inject 'components' into my pages.  At present, I am rendering out components in a fairly simple way such as follows:

`<latest-blog-posts limit="3" order-by="date asc"/>`

I then want to use **TagHelpers** to fill in the real content.  Is there a way to call a controller action in ASP.NET Core and replace the invoking tag with the resulting view.  My feeling is that I need to be looking at using `output.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)`, but I'm stuck on how to feed the response from an Action into the writer.

Comment: why do you want to call the action method from tag helper ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do make my views and models as simple as possible.  I receive a collection of _potential_ components with basic collections of properties.  I can easily render these out as the tags I mentioned above, but in reality, each component can be complex. In the example, I need to call the CMS and retrieve the three most recent blog posts.  I have an inbuilt hatred of editing HTML in back-end code and decided that managing each component in a controller with a view of some kind would give me more flexibility and reusability throughout my application.

Comment: tag helpers should be used for rendering content, not making more requests back to the server.  Could you achieve what you want by using partial views and child actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components). They're similar in function to the way child actions used to work in MVC 5 and previous.

```
public class LatestBlogPostsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly BlogDbContext db;

    public LatestBlogPostsViewComponent(BlogDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int limit, string orderBy)
    {
        var posts = // get latest posts;
        return View(posts);
    }
}
```

Next, create the view `Views/Shared/Components/LatestBlogPosts.cshtml` and add the code you'd like to render your list of latest blog posts. Your view's model will be the type of `posts` returned by the view component.

Finally, in the view or layout where you want the latest blog posts to be rendered call the component using:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("LatestBlogPosts", new { limit = 3, orderBy = "date asc" })
```

Or, if you prefer the TagHelper syntax:

```
<vc:latest-blog-posts limit="3" orderBy="date asc"></vc:latest-blog-posts>
```

The latter method requires that you [register the view component(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components#invoking-a-view-component-as-a-tag-helper).